# How to make painted canvas fit all screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, dpi

How to make the images painted in canvas valid for all screen sizes? my code but it doesn't work, the painted game screen is too large for small screens and too small for large screens, I have tried everything and nothing works still, I want the canvas to scale according to the screen's size

this is the result I get and the desired result: https://imgur.com/a/bSnGfov

Here's my code for the game canvas:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    Me me;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int fx,fy,zx,zy;
    int[][]lines;
    private Bitmap pme, wall,finish,redlock,redkey,bluelock,bluekey,greenlock,greenkey ,mBitmap,white,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
            ,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    Context context;
    private Paint p;
    private int mx, my,character;private int dir;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;float bb;string bbb; int sz;int fz;
    public CanvasView(Context c,int[][] l,Me m,int mxx,int myy,int chara) {
        super(c);
        lines=l;
        mx = mxx;
        my = myy;
        context = c;
        fx=6;fy=6;zx=0;zy=0;
        me = m;
        character=chara;
        mPath = new Path();

        p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        p.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    // override onSizeChanged
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    // override onDraw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = mx;
        int height = my;float calc = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        canvas.drawBitmap(pme,calc*( (me.GetCenterX() - 24)+zx),calc*( (me.GetCenterY() - 24)+zy), p);
        int px = (me.GetCenterX() - 24) / 48;
        int py = (me.GetCenterY() - 24) / 48;
        for (int j = 0; j < fx; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fy; i++)
                if (i < height)
                {

                    float tileX = ((j * 48) + zx) * calc;
                    float tileY = ((i * 48) + zy) * calc;
                    int type = lines[i][j];
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(wall, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(finish, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bluelock, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bluekey, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(redlock, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(redkey, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(greenlock, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(greenkey, tileX,tileY, p);
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++ )
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(white, 6*48* calc,i*48* calc, p);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(white, j*48* calc,6*48* calc, p);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically request the dimensions of your Android device's screen.

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 int width = size.x;
 int height = size.y;
```

Get a handle on the current display - note that if you call from the application context, you will get the size of your physical screen.  If you call from the activity, you will get the current size of the app window.

Comment: Thank you, and afterwards what should I do?

Comment: It looks like in the onDraw() method you are setting `width = mx` and `height=my`.  Instead of setting these values to `mx`, `my`, try setting them to the height and width values you pull from the above code :)